# Rails `unitialized constant` for a constant defined in app/classes subdirectory in staging env

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

the error happens in :staging environment only

`config/initializers/activity_api.rb:4:in 'block in <top (required)>'`

```
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  config = YAML.load_file('config/activity.yml')[Rails.env] || {}
  config.deep_symbolize_keys!
  Activity::API.config = config
end
```

And I have `Activity::API` class definition in `app/classes/activity/api.rb`

```
module Activity
  class API
  ...
  end
end
```

Shall I explicitely define a module `Activity` in `app/classes/activity.rb` and require files in `app/classes/activity` or there is something I misunderstand?

Maybe app/classes subdirectories are not in autoload path?

Answer (score 0):

Creating an empty module `Activity` would help.

You can also try to user the inline class declaration style:

```
class Activity::Api
end
```

Comment: maybe the unicorn process hasn't restarted, and runs on the old code?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Finally I found that unicorn hadn't restarted and worked with the release directory that were deleted by Capistrano.